# When algorithm2e package is used in elsart format, the line number will be marked outside the box. How to solve it?

Tags: latex

I want to write pesudo code used algorithm2e package in elsart style. Found that algorithm2e package will have the same name conflict with the macro in eslart. After the conflict is solved by substitution, another problem appears that:it is the line number of the pseudo code written will be marked outside the box. the code as follow:

```
\documentclass{elsart}
\usepackage[algo2e,ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
{
\begin{algorithm2e}
\caption{Another algorithm with caption}\label{alg:three}
\KwData{Write here the required data}
\KwResult{Write here the expected result}
 initialization\;
 \While{While condition}{
  instructions\;
  \eIf{condition}{
   instructions1\;
   instructions2\;
   }{
   instructions3\;
  }
 }
\end{algorithm2e}
}
\end{document}
```

The screenshot of the problem is as follows：

[image]

Normally, this should be the case：

[image]

Comment: Please make a [mre] that reproduces the problem instead of the `article` class which works fine

Comment: Can you add a link where we can get the class from?

Comment: I am sorry I make a mistake in writing. The document class is elsart, which is the Elsevier article class. we can get from this link: https://arxiv.org/macros/elsart.cls. This document class may cause problems in the alignment of pseudo code line numbers in the algorithm

Answer (score 2):

The `elsart` class changes the `\parindent`. You can counteract this by adjusting the  `\algomargin`:

```
\documentclass{elsart}

\usepackage[algo2e,ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

{
\setlength{\algomargin}{1.5em}
\begin{algorithm2e}
\caption{Another algorithm with caption}\label{alg:three}
\KwData{Write here the required data}
\KwResult{Write here the expected result}
 initialization\;
 \While{While condition}{
  instructions\;
  \eIf{condition}{
   instructions1\;
   instructions2\;
   }{
   instructions3\;
  }
 }
\end{algorithm2e}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]